# 2016 Presidential candidates with some background in mathematics

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

My question is simple enough: are there any presidential candidates for the 2016 election that have some formal training in mathematics?

What I'm looking for here is someone with at least a bachelors in Mathematics.  Assuming there are none, are there any candidates that have received a university degree that would have required extensive mathematics?  (Physicists, economists, basically any hard science...)

EDIT:  While an MD goes through quite a bit of technical training, I would like to discount these for this specific question.  Usually MDs get into a bit of calculus, I'm looking for a bit more mathematics than this.

Comment: Does an MD count under a hard science requirement?

Comment: Oh, i forgot to mention that in the question.  I'll edit it in a second.  While it is a very technical field, I would prefer not to consider MDs.

Comment: If I may, what if the question was slightly expanded: What are the educational degrees each candidate holds?

Comment: [James Garfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_A._Garfield#Legal_career_and_other_activities) had his own proof of the Pythagorean theorem based on the properties of trapezoids.  Obviously not an answer to this question, but an interesting point of trivia in relation to Presidential math ability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Donald Trump [studied economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump) in college. Other than that, the closest I could find is that Lindsay Graham and Ben Carson studied psychology as undergraduates, and Rand Paul practiced as an ophthalmologist. None of the other candidates studied sciences.

Wikipedia pages for all candidates:

Democratic Candidates:

- [Jim Webb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Webb)
- [Bernie Sanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernie_Sanders#Early_life_and_education)
- [Hillary Clinton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton)
- [Martin O'Malley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_O%27Malley)
- [Lincoln Chafee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln_Chafee)

Republican Candidates:

- [Jeb Bush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeb_Bush)
- [Ben Carson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Carson)
- [Chris Christie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Christie)
- [Ted Cruz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Cruz)
- [Carly Fiorina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carly_Fiorina)
- [Lindsay Graham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindsey_Graham)
- [Mike Huckabee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Huckabee)
- [Bobby Jindal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Jindal)
- [John Kasich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Kasich)
- [George Pataki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Pataki)
- [Rand Paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_Paul)
- [Rick Perry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Perry)
- [Marco Rubio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Rubio)
- [Rick Santorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Santorum)
- [Donald Trump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump)
- [Scott Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Walker)

Comment: Neil deGrasse Tyson needs to run.

Comment: @PointlessSpike - we already let scientists run the government once. That [Didn't End Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Revolution)

Comment: "Inspired by liberal and radical ideas, the Revolution profoundly altered the course of modern history, triggering the global decline of absolute monarchies while replacing them with republics." It may have been carried out badly, but that doesn't invalidate the idea. If you'd like to discuss it further, we could do so in chat.

Comment: @Avi Rand Paul was an optometrist/ophthalmologist (eyes), not an obstetrician (pregnancy)

Comment: @costrom Thanks for pointing that out; I'd misread the wikipedia article (Ron Paul was the obstetrician).

Comment: Looking at the minor parties, Jill Stein studied social science then medicine, and Gary Johnson political science. (Source: Wikipedia). Leonid Brezhnev, a Soviet leader, was a metallurgical engineer, which I assume involves a lot of math.